# Unable get response on jsp call using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

Here below is my `jsp call`:

```
NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://xxx.com/xx/jsp/Implementation/getMyResource.jsp?uid=xxxxx"];
NSURL *urlLink = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:strURL];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlLink];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
operation.responseSerializer = [AFXMLParserResponseSerializer serializer];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSXMLParser *xmlParser = (NSXMLParser*)responseObject;
    NSLog(@"%@",xmlParser);

    NSError * parsedError = nil;

    NSDictionary *dictUserDetails = [XMLReader dictionaryForNSXMLParser:xmlParser error:&parsedError];

    if (parsedError == nil) {
        NSLog(@"%@",dictUserDetails);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"wrong while parsing xml data");
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *request, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error:------>%@", [error description]);
}];
```

`No response` at all. When i `paste` `strURL link` in `web browser` i `get response` instantly, so `no problem` in `url`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your `AFHTTPRequestOperation` to the queue:

`[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];`

See https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#get-with-afhttprequestoperation